# How to show lock screen over user blocked app using app lock

Tags: android, applocker

I am working on an app lock android project. After seeing many sources, I  was able to write a service which detects whenever an app is launched and check whether it is in the blocked list of apps which user want to lock and show a lock screen above it.

Some of the apps have a splash screen in front of their main activity. Generally, these apps show a splash activity for some time and then jumps to its main activity.

Here is where problem comes....my service was able to recognize the app launch, shows a lock screen over it, but while user was entering password, if it is the kind of app which has splash screen in front of main activity....its main activity comes up suddenly over my lock screen even before user enters his password.

There is any procedure to block intents which change top activity for some time.

I would appreciate help with this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you show the lock screen? Did you write your own? Also, what's your min SDK version?

Comment: Yeah.....I wrote my own lockscreen activity and called it with intent from service when I found a blocked app.My min sdk is 22